# Angular - MongoDB Direct CRUD

Tags: angular, mongodb, rest, server, crud

I searched and  could not find so many resources best fit for my topic.
All I need to now, how can I make CRUD operations directly from my Angular client to the MongoDB.
I found some topics which do not recommend such structure, but not clarifying how to do it.
Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Anglar Universal that allow SSR (server side rendering). https://angular.io/guide/universal

There is a tutorial that use Mongo "**Building a full CRUD Angular 8 Universal and MongoDB SSR**": https://morioh.com/p/cc795826322e

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I checked the links, but that structures contain a server side technologies. Is there any way to connect mongodb without any server side component?

Comment: No, you need a server to use mongo and the only way to use mongo inside angular is to have angular inside server x)

Comment: Hi, 
Allow me to clarify my question furthermore. It is always told that is not a secure way to connect Angular to Database directly. I just need to know how to Connect angular to the MongoDB directly **without sending an http request to node** which then does the database connection. How to directly send queries to database from the angular app and **surpass** the node application?

Comment: You cannot. How expect you the request to the database executed within static files ?